# How to limit the rebound angle in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I'm new to Unity and I would like to add a constraint to the rebound of a ball, I can not...

Let me explain. I would like to limit the bounce angle of my ball to 5° whatever the inclination of my platform.

See the diagram below:

[image]

Can you help me please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like you're going to want to handle the rebound programmatically, since this doesn't adhere to the normal physics implementation. Have you tried any approaches to this problem yet?

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying something with "addForce" to simulate a rebound and then compensate the rebound angle with an opposite x force.

Comment: I see - it would be helpful to include that code attempt in your question, so it gives us a better idea of the context of the problem, and how you're currently approaching it.